# i am getting error like validation error and also 404 error and enter all field..please check it...i also attached an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLw2.png)

Im giving all details in form filed still i get the error: enter all fields....

and also im gettind error like /api/user 404 not found dont know why

if i try this in postman i get the output as expexted
but not in frontend part

My userController.js file

```js
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
// const res = require('express/lib/response');
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");
const User = require("../Models/userModel");

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password || !name) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("please enter all fields");
  }

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("user already exists");
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    pic,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error("user not found");
  }
});

const authuser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Invalid Email or Password");
  }
});

module.exports = { registerUser, authuser };
```

My userRoutes.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const{ registerUser  , authuser}= require('../controller/userController');


const router = express.Router();

router.route('/').post(registerUser) 
router.route('/login').post(authuser);

module.exports = router;
```

My Signup.js

```html
import { Button, FormControl, FormLabel, Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement, toast, useToast, VStack } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import axios from 'axios'
// import res from 'express/lib/response'
// import res from 'express/lib/response'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Signup = () => {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const [showcon, setShowcon] = useState(false)
    const [name, setName] = useState()
    const [email, setemail] = useState()
    const [confirmpassword, setconfirmpassword] = useState()
    const [password, setpassword] = useState()
    const [pic, setPic] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)   
    const toast = useToast();
    const history = useHistory()

    const postDetails = (pics)=> {
        setLoading(true)
        if(pics===undefined){
            toast({
                title:'Please select an image',
                status:'warning',
                duration:5000,
                isClosable:true,
                position:'bottom'
            })
            return;
        } 
        console.log(pics)
        if(pics.type==="image/jpeg" || pics.type === "image/png")
        {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append("file" ,pics);
            data.append("upload_preset" , "chat-app");
            data.append("cloud_name" , "dxvwfoybv")
            fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dxvwfoybv/image/upload" , {
                method:'post', body:data,
            }).then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setPic(data.url.toString());
                console.log(data.url.toString());
                setLoading(false);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setLoading(false);
            })
        }else{
            toast({
                title: "Please Select an Image!",
                status: "warning",
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: "bottom",
              });
              setLoading(false);
              return;
        }
    }

    const handleClick =() => {
        setShow(!show);
    }

    const submithandler =async() => {
        //  setLoading(true);
         if(!name || !email || !password || !confirmpassword){
             toast({
                 title:"please fill all details",
                 status: 'warning',
                 duration:'5000',
                 isClosable:true,
                 position:'bottom'
             })
             return;
         }

         try {
             const config = {
                 headers: {
                     "content-type" : "application/json",

                 }
             }
             const data  = await axios.post("/api/user" , {name , email , password , pic}. config);

             toast({
                 title:"Registration successfull",
                 status: "success",
                 duration: 5000,
                 position: "bottom",
                 isClosable: true
             })
             localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));

             setLoading(false);
             history.push('/chats')

         } catch (error) {
             toast({
                title:"Error occured",
                status: "error",
                description:error.response.data.message,
                duration: 5000,
                position: "bottom",
                isClosable: true
             })
         }
    }

    
    // const handleClickcon =() => {
    //     setShowcon(!showcon)
    // }

    console.log()

  return (
      <>
    <VStack spacing='5px'>
        
        <FormControl name='firstname'>
            <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
               <Input
                    
                    placeholder='Enter Your Name'
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
               /> 
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
               <Input
                    type='email'
                    placeholder='Enter Your Email address'
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e)=>setemail(e.target.value)}
               /> 
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <InputGroup>
               <Input

                    type={show?  "" : "password"}
                    placeholder='Enter Your Password'
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e)=>setpassword(e.target.value)}
               /> 

                <InputRightElement width='4.5rem'>
                    <Button h='1.75rem' size='sm' onClick={handleClick}>
                        {
                            show? "Hide" : "Show"
                        }    
                    </Button>

                </InputRightElement>

            </InputGroup>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Confirm Password</FormLabel>
            <InputGroup>
               <Input

                    type={show?  "" : "password"}
                    placeholder='Enter Your Password'
                    value={confirmpassword}
                    onChange={(e)=>setconfirmpassword(e.target.value)}
               /> 

                <InputRightElement width='4.5rem'>
                    
                            
                    

                </InputRightElement>

            </InputGroup>
        </FormControl>

        <FormControl>
            <FormLabel>Upload your Picture</FormLabel>
            <Input type='file' p='1.5' accept='image/*' onChange={(e) => postDetails(e.target.files[0])}>                
            </Input>

        </FormControl>  


        <Button
            colorScheme='blue'
            width='100%'
            style={{marginTop: '20px'}}
            onClick={submithandler}
            isLoading={loading}
        >Sign up</Button>      
    
    </VStack>

    </>
  )
}

export default Signup
```

Comment: `{name , email , password , pic}. config` should be `{name , email , password , pic}, config` - currently your request is `await axios.post("/api/user", undefined)` due to that typo - did you use the browser developer tools to check what was being sent in the request? Not sure why the 404 is a mystery to you, the `404 not found` is because that's the status YOU send in YOUR code when `(!email || !password || !name)`

Comment: But if i fill all this details....then why still I'm getting 404 ...?

Comment: did you understand the TYPO in your code that I pointed out? ... `{name,email ,password,pic}.config` results in ONE argument, `undefined` .... where as `{name,email ,password,pic}, config` results in two arguments, the object you want as a body, and the `config` you want as the config argument ... it's a TYPO ... you put `. config` instead of `, config` - and the 404 is because the server doesn't get the info, because of the TYPO your browser isn't SENDING ANYTHING ... because of the TYPO ... note: TYPO is short for typographical error ... you've used `.` instead of `,` ... do you understand?

Comment: TL;DR `{name,email ,password,pic}. config` is valid JS syntax, but it's NOT what you want to do - you want `{name,email ,password,pic}, config` **can you spot the difference**?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from the request body the front send. In the front code, make a console log of the body request before it sent and show us.

Comment: hey brother please check the new code for signup.js that i added  @louisBrochet